# How to infer type of function argument in "proxy" function

Tags: typescript, parameters, tuples

I am attempting to implement a "proxy" method, which is able to call other methods of the class dynamically. All works well until I start playing around with types of other methods arguments. Following example gives `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.`

What am I doing wrong? According to [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype), `Parameters` utility function returns tuple :(

```js
class testClass {
  public methodA(a: number): void {
  }

  public methodB(b: string): void {
  }

  public callRandom(methodName: 'methodA', options: [number]): void;
  public callRandom(methodName: 'methodB', options: [string]): void;
  public callRandom(methodName: 'methodA' | 'methodB', options: [number] | [string]) {
      type optionsType = Parameters<this[typeof methodName]>; 
      this[methodName](...options as optionsType);
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAuCmFYGFxWgbwFDWgBwFcAjEAS2GgFt5YALAewBMBBACjAC5oA7Ayo+ACcAlFwBu9Uo0w5oAXyyzCJclRoNGAIVZEuSQaW4BzUdAlSZuBUuJkKwMCBAAlMN0b1KranSYA5MGouAHIfDWZggBpoejxYUnpuCC4AbV5+IQBdU3NGAG4bFXtHFzcPLzD-QPgQyq0omLiEpNT0gUFs8Ul8wrtoBydXd09vdSqg6FCxlmDoAB9Jus0G2PjE5Og0vnbM+c39QyNsy1xT2ABPPHhGtaSAFUvrgF5oAAUwQWqEQQgAHjpSBAUhcrvQAGZqXyMALUTIAPjy0Fkp3661gcEejAA8k11tAXqtmjBIDciQ8rsizrRASk6jD4JlWAA6Fkg+DY3FJYQFKxYORAA)

Comment: This is a bug or design limitation of TS, see [ms/TS#42508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42508) and [ms/TS#36874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36874).  If you want to just push ahead you can use a type assertion as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WyQ0xW), but the "right" way to write this is using generics as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/W4Q97w).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes, this resolved my issue. I would be amazing if you could expend on the `[never]` in your answer, since I can not say I understand why it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into a known bug / limitation of TypeScript, described at [microsoft/TypeScript#36874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36874) and [microsoft/TypeScript#42508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42508) (and issues linked therein).  If you're trying to [spread something into a function call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_function_calls) TypeScript currently only seems to allow that if its type is a single [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  [Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of tuples, or [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) that are [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to tuples, or [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that evaluate to tuples are not supported.

If you want to just push ahead and prevent the error, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
  public callRandom(methodName: 'methodA' | 'methodB', options: [number] | [string]) {
    type optionsType = Parameters<this[typeof methodName]>;
    this[methodName](...options as [never]);
  }
```

So, `[never]` is a single tuple type, so it's seen as spreadable.  But why `never`?  That's because the compiler has no idea whether `methodName` is `"methodA"` or `"methodB"`.  It's a *union* of the two.  So `this[methodName]` will be a union of functions.  And a union of functions can only be called safely with an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of its parameter types.  See [the TS3.3 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) for a description of that functionality.  Since `methodA` wants a `number`, and `methodB` wants a `string`, you can only safely pass something which is *both* a `number` *and* a `string`, so it doesn't matter which method you're calling.  Uh, but there is no such thing.  `number & string` is reduced to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  Thus the only thing the compiler will let you pass as `options` is `[never]`.

You might be thinking that `methodName` and `options` are *correlated* to each other in such a way that it's always appropriate to call `this[methodName](...options)`, but that correlation is not something the compiler sees.  The implementation of your function has `methodName` and `options` as two *independent* union types, so as far as the compiler knows inside that implementation, it's quite possible for `methodName` to be `"methodA"` while `options` is `[string]`.  TypeScript really doesn't have direct support for correlated unions, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

---

If you want the compiler to actually "understand" that `this[methodName](...options)` is always appropriate, then you need to refactor your code as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The idea is to move away from unions (and [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) in your case), and toward generics.  You represent your operations in terms of a "basic" key-value type, and in terms of generic [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that type, and in terms of generic indexes into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.

For your example it might look like

```
interface MethodParam {
  methodA: [number],
  methodB: [string]
}

class TestClass {
  public methodA(a: number): void {
  }

  public methodB(b: string): void {
  }

  public callRandom<K extends keyof MethodParam>(
    methodName: K, 
    options: MethodParam[K]
  ) {
    const t: { [P in keyof MethodParam]: (...args: MethodParam[P]) => void } = this;
    t[methodName](...options);
  }
}
```

The basic type is `MethodParam`, and we assign `this` to a variable `t` of the mapped type `{ [P in keyof MethodParam]: (...args: MethodParam[P]) => void }`.  The compiler sees that assignment as acceptable (because it goes through each property of `MethodParam` and can verify that `TestClass` has an appropriately shaped method at that property).  And `methodName` is a key of `MethodParam` of generic type `K`.  And `options` is a generic index into `MethodParam`, `MethodParam[K]`.

Now `t[methodName]` is a generic index into that mapped type, and can be seen as the single function type `(...args: MethodParam[K]) => void`.  Since `options` is of type `MethodParam[K]`, then `t[methodName](...options)` is acceptable.  No unions of functions are involved, and no intersections of parameters are required.

This refactoring might not be worth it for your use case.  You might care more about expedience ("stop complaining, compiler, and let me get on with my day") than protection ("I need you to understand what I'm doing, compiler, so that if I make a mistake you'll catch it").  If so, then a type assertion is the way to go.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDB2EMFsFMGcAdwGNoAIBSTwBsBeqBvYVVCGBZNAQVlmgCcAXQ4k1JbcW1AFTkYDCnbkTZt4AVwBG2AJZJUMRgAsA9gBMqACnAAuUhMhSGASn0A3VbPUsxJAL4g7qSTPmLoKjQCEtU-bCM9LKgAOZmqJbWtnaOrGKucgpY2NgASuCg6qqQWkpq6gByUND6AOT5GlRlADSoqvCMsqqgsPoA2qCGxvQAuhFR6gDc8eLSSew46ZnZuZVFJeXz3rX1jc2tHYHBYf0WVsOjJInuKdNZOXmeBcUwS9dVZagAPqgVD+ordQ1NLW2onW6DF6LwB2xCoX6MWcjAAnvA0D8NrAePC0ABeVAABXA9BKjAYsAAPCpZLB2nCEaoAGYeLwLGC9AB8I2cJFJ5Pmt2gvS0ADoBUi-qguADQNBzMCTKzYqM4g4QHEyHBEChUABxaDi4IKUSoVghAn0amUVAAWQ+OLxkGhdIKVA6XSMwJqo2WWyCEN6rHl7GEsF4-CEXADeuO43c820egMzvoAwOtt94bcCmWfgCnrCCeiYdQyZcEeSUwyF0gRIA0qhoAAPAlZAMAa2gsJp5stuKgTKu9O5+gr33Wf30FvpVqg7QrULzJCQf2YjH0BABWNQIVQzdbtNHBXHkF6+n5AtxoX+O40e-aWKh6KZkUT9lQmI5MrEjHaXJKvIFfKFrWlco+iAwD2EAA)